Solving a system of Over-determined Non-Linear Trigonometric equations
Given a system of Non-Linear Trigonometric equations i.e. the terms in each equation are either variables raised to some power, trigonometric functions ($\sin, \cos$) raised to some power or product of these two. Moreover this system is over-determined i.e. there are more equations than unknown variables.
Query: Is it always easy to solve (real valued solution) such a system (assuming a solution exists). If yes, how do we solve it?
The closest I have come across is this:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overdetermined_system#Overdetermined_nonlinear_systems_of_equations
which states that "As an effective method for solving overdetermined systems, the Gauss-Newton iteration locally quadratically converges to solutions.."
So do i understand correctly that such a system can always be solved efficiently? If yes can someone provide a reference for laymen where the approach with some solved examples is discussed in detail?
